# Monet db performance issue while updating data

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, database-performance, monetdb

In monetdb, I have to update data depending on the next row value, For this i have used update query with self join like below. We have almost 1 million records in the table, it is causing the performance issue and breaking down. I used the below query.Please suggest is there any better way to improve the performance.
My requirement is to update a column gap_flag with data(gap between two consecutive rows).

```
`update temp_tbl_gaps_consolidated_table 
        set gap_flag =  (entry_time - ( select a.exit_time+ interval'1' second 
                                         from 
                                         temp_tbl_gaps_consolidated_table a
     where a.row_num =(temp_tbl_gaps_consolidated_table.row_num-1) and 
    a.zone_id = temp_tbl_gaps_consolidated_table.zone_id and 
    a.multiday_entity_pk = temp_tbl_gaps_consolidated_table.multiday_entity_pk)
    )/1000;`
```